# Issues Proffering Language Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, languageservice

I have found two ways of proffering a language service on the internet.

[The first way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb166498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) involves using a `IOleComponentManager` and registering a timer to call my service during idle times.

[The second way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37f5e070-454b-4a1a-83f8-4c0ee3290019/problem-with-language-service-walkthrough?forum=vsx) involves casing my service as an `IServiceContainer` and adding a `ServiceCreatorCallback` to "proffer the service on demand".

Supposedly the second way is now the "preferred way" of doing things.  Unfortunately, when I use this method, `OnSynchronizeDropdowns` never gets called on my `TypeAndMembersDropdownBars` implementation.

In addition, when my `LanguageService` finds errors in the file, it uses `ParseRequest.Sink.AddError()` to add errors to the error list.  When proffering "On Demand", these errors don't show up in the GUI, even though I see them being added when I debug through the code.

I know that my language service is being registered, because syntax highlighting, "Go to Defintion", and "Find All References" still work.

Here is the code I'm using to "proffer my service on demand":

```
IServiceContainer serviceContainer = this as IServiceContainer;
ServiceCreatorCallback callback = new ServiceCreatorCallback(CreateLanguageService);
serviceContainer.AddService(typeof(MyLanguageService), callback, true);
```

**Can anyone tell me why some functionality of my `LanguageService` does not work when proffering it on demand?  Am I missing something, or is that way just not meant for a fully functional language service?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Amy The question is about how to proffer a custom language service the right way, so that Visual Studio interacts with it as expected... the problem is, that there are various ways to do the language service registration, but not all ways of doing it lead to the correct behavior.

Comment: @Amy I updated my question with a clear summary of what I'm asking.

Comment: Can someone tell me what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like at least the missing functionality requires using the `IOleComponentManager` method that registers a timer to call the language service during **idle periods**.

Using [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), I found that `OnSynchronizeDropdowns()` gets called from `OnCaretMoved()` for synchronizing the selected item when you click around in the editor.  `OnCaretMoved()` itself appears to only be called from the `LanguageService.OnIdle()` method, which I believe requires the use of the idle timer.

After digging some more, I also found that the error list requires that the `ParseRequest.Reason` be set to `ParseReason.Check`, otherwise it ignores the call.  Digging through the code some more, the only place I found that parse reason being used was in `Source.OnIdle()`.

**Update:** I believe I have confirmed that registering an idle timer is required for these two pieces of functionality.  From MSDN on [LanguageService.OnIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.languageservice.onidle.aspx):

> **Note**
> This method is not called unless you set up your own timer and call
> this method from the timer handler.
>
> The base method calls [OnCaretMoved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.languageservice.oncaretmoved.aspx) if the caret has moved since last
> time **OnIdle** was called. The base method then calls the OnIdle method
> on the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.source.aspx) object for the current view. If the current [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.source.aspx)
> object cannot be obtained, the base method does nothing at all,
> including not calling [OnCaretMoved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.languageservice.oncaretmoved.aspx).

Comment: For an MPF language service, this is correct. Proffering the language service instance is a separate operation from performing background updates within that instance. My [LangSvcV2](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/LangSvcV2/) project does not base its language services on MPF. In that code, an [event listener is added to `ITextCaret.PositionChanged`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/LangSvcV2/blob/master/Tvl.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation/Navigation/EditorNavigationDropdownBar.cs#L114) in order to synchronize the drop downs.

Comment: Note that the latter strategy will also be used in the [VSBase service implementation](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/issues/9) of this feature, since it requires fewer steps for the user to remember.

Comment: "The latter strategy" being the event listener mentioned in your comment, the second method mentioned in my question, or a combination of both (my current assumption)?  (I'd take a look at your GitHub repository to see for myself, but I don't have the time at the moment.)

Comment: The LangSvcV2 project is not structured in a way that works with other language implementations. The VSBase project will initially use an implementation of this feature similar to the one in LangSvcV2, but it will be refactored into new assemblies in a way that allows it to be reliably used by a variety of other extensions.